# Can you remove 000 file extension after a CSV unload from Amazon Redshift to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I've code which extracts data from redshift to S3

```
UNLOAD ('

select sysdate

')

TO 's3://test-bucket/adretarget/test.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=ABCDE;aws_secret_access_key=12345' 
ALLOWOVERWRITE
delimiter ',' 
PARALLEL OFF ;
```

It works ok, however all my files end .csv000 is there a way to exclude the 000 so they just end.csv

Thanks

Comment: What is the amount of data that you are unloading from Redshift? If the size of data is greater than 6.2GB, then the data will be written in multiple files. Those multiple file names will be appended by an increment three digit numbers.

Comment: Hi, It varies, most are below 6.2GB, but sometimes it can be above

Answer (score -5):

```
    UNLOAD ('

select sysdate

')

TO 's3://test-bucket/adretarget/test' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=ABCDE;aws_secret_access_key=12345' 
ALLOWOVERWRITE
delimiter ',' 
PARALLEL OFF ;
```

There is no need to add the .csv extension in your unload file name. You can just mention 'test' and it will unload your data without extension, but the file will still be comma separated, which is csv.

Comment: Thanks, I still get the file with 000 at the end though.

Comment: Yes, because thats the naming convention unload uses in order to avoid duplicate names which I believe cannot be avoided from our end.

Comment: ok, thanks. I wondered if that was the case. Thanks again